# FLVPlayback component check cross-domain policy file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, streaming, cross-domain, flv

I'm using the FLVPlayback component to stream video in my application. When using Bitmap draw, I get a SecurityError:

> SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: No policy files granted access

I have a policy file on both my web server and my FMS. I believe the issue is that the FLVPlayback component doesn't have an option to check for a policy file. I've tried:

```
flvpb.getVideoPlayer(pb.activeVideoPlayerIndex).netStream.checkPolicyFile = true;
```

But, this was unsuccessful as the activeVideoPlayerIndex is null until the video is loaded. The problem with this is that the policy file needs to be checked prior to the load.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is just a guess, but are you able to set the activeVideoPlayerIndex before loading?  The docs seem to suggest that this will create a new video player instance for you, which you might be able to then access and set the checkPolicyFile flag on.  (I'd test it out myself, but I'm more of a Flex guy and don't have a copy of Flash Professional)

Comment: Is the Policy files even being loaded? use HTTPFox for FireFox to test it. Have you tried Security.allowDomain( domain )

Comment: I've also found it helpful to use Fiddler or Wireshark to verify if Flash Player is actually making a policy request, and to what URL.

Comment: Actually, activeVideoPlayerIndex isn't null...and getVideoPlayer(activeVideoPlayerIndex) actually returns a video player. The NetStream object is null. I can try attaching a NetStream object, but I might as well create my own video player class. @The_asMan I have Security.allowDomain("*") and Security.loadPolicyFile("path/to/file"). I have confirmed that the policy file is loading.

Comment: The other thing I would suggest then is to turn on policy file logging and see if that sheds any light on the issue: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html#_Using_Logging

Comment: Why is it I feel you are not giving all the info. Somehow, I suspect there is otherstuff being loaded into the swf that is not from the same domain. I am beginning to think this is not a video issue at all, but more of an image issue. Post the code where you are doing your bitmap.draw

Comment: Actually, I have discovered that the issue is on the FMS side. `checkPolicyFile` is ignored when using RTMP. I'm still not sure if you can set `checkPolicyFile` inside the FLVPlayback or if it's default is true.